# autosuggest_text_field placing the object title as value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use `sunspot_autocomplete` to create an autosuggest field. Current code looks like the following.

```
= autosuggest_text_field('dvd', 'title', search_index_path, 'dvd_title')
```

Problem is that since this search input is placed on the header of the application file, when visiting a dvd page, I see its title placed as value on the input.

Is there any way to prevent this?